# What is the best query to get the latest row version based on time?

Tags: oracle, performance, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

I'm wondering what can be the most efficient query to get the latest rows from the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE AGE_DATA
(
  INSERTED_DAY TIMESTAMP(6),
  HOSTNAME VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  CONCEPT  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  REPORTED_VALUE NUMBER(10)
);
```

If I want to know the latest data inserted by hostname, I have 2 approaches, and I want to know which would be the most efficient, depending the cases a) having ~100 rows, b) having more than ~1M rows.

```
with latest as (select hostname,max(inserted_day) inserted_day 
from AGE_DATA group by hostname)
select * 
from latest l
join age_data ad on (l.hostname = ad.hostname and l.inserted_day = ad.inserted_day)
```

or

```
select * from age_data 
where (hostname,inserted_day) in (select hostname,max(inserted_day) inserted_day 
    from AGE_DATA group by hostname)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This looks like Oracle. I suggest creating a test table and collecting execution plans and traces for both the queries. It can be that the with-clause leads to a materialization of the subquery which can have some IO overhead. There's an oracle hint to turn it off.

Comment: @Phil it is oracle, but I would like to make it agnostic, so it can be used in other RDBMS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 3rd option, using window functions, either `max()`:

```
with latest as 
(select *,
        max(inserted_day) over (partition by hostname)
          as max_inserted_day 
 from age_data
)
select *              
from latest l
where inserted_day = max_inserted_day ;
```

or `rank()`:

```
with latest as 
(select *,
        rank() over (partition by hostname order by inserted_day desc)
          as rnk
 from age_data
)
select *              
from latest l
where rnk = 1 ;
```

If there are ties (rows with same maximum `inserted_day` for a `hostname`), all the above queries (and yours) will return all the tied rows. If you want to resolve ties (and return only 1 or only 2 rows), you can replace `rank()` with `row_number()` and change the `order by` clause inside the `over` according to the requirements.

Regarding efficiency, an index on `(hostname, inserted_day)` will help, in all the queries.

Comment: I won't bother for the ties, to avoid that I would have used unique keys. Interesting proposal.

Comment: Yes, if there is a unique constraint on `(hostname, inserted_day)`, all the above (max, rank, row_number) will  return the same result.

Comment: I love the windowing function/cte combination. So much power, so easy to read

Comment: Just found your alternative elegant. Thanks!